# Import android call logs and display it

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have made a contact application for android. It has the basic features of adding contacts, deleting contacts, call and sms. Now I wish to add an extra feature which is importing call logs from the phone and display it. This is the coding that I have tried:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".call_log"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the call_log.java file:

```
public class call_log extends Activity {
    TextView textView = null;
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call);
      getCallDetails();
     }

     private void getCallDetails() {

          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          Cursor managedQuery = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery;
          int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
          int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
          int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
          int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
          sb.append("Call Log :");
          while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
           String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
           String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
           String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
           Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
           String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
           String dir = null;
           int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
           switch (dircode) {
           case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

           case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

           case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
           }
           sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
             + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
             + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
           sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
          }
          //managedCursor.close();
          textView.setText(sb);
         }
```

Source code credit to [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/android-call-history-example-how-to-get.html).
I get the error at the call_log.java file. The error is textview_call cannot be resolved or is not a field.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a minimum amount of effort (e.g. code examples).

Comment: I have tried the tutorial from this [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/android-call-history-example-how-to-get.html). However, the code for the xml file doesnt work for me. I just learn java this semester and I dont know much about it.

Comment: "doesnt work" is not a very precise statement. Edit your question to precisely describe your problem, what you tried and whether you got any problem-related error messages.

Comment: _"Please help me"_ is not a question. You need to show the code you're having trouble with, and explain what the problem is (i.e. what it _is_ doing and what it _should be_ doing), including logs and error messages if there are any.

Comment: Okay, just the question (or problem) is missing. Does the code crash? Won't it compile? Are there error messages?

Comment: Did you place the layout file in `res/layout`? Are you using gradle?

Comment: I put it in res->layout->call_log.xml. When I check the R.java file, there is no R.id.textview_call in it.

Comment: Did you try a complete rebuild? Using gradle: `gradlew clean build assembleDebug`

Comment: I didnt try a complete rebuild. How to do it?